# Using CFNotificationCenterAddObserver in background (Swift and Flutter)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, background-process

I'm trying to develop my first app and one of its features is to monitor if phone is locked or my app is active (in foreground).
To do this i listen for app life cycle changes and "com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen" on Swift (Should evaluate true if phone is Sleeping or my App is active, false if other app is activated after phone wake-up).

This is my Dart code:

```
static const detectDeviceAwakeining = MethodChannel('tidy/detectDeviceAwakeining');
...
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    detectDeviceAwakeining.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      print("Device screen state changed Dart");
    });
    ...
}
```

And my Swift code:

```
let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                    observer,
                                    hasBlankedScreen,
                                    "com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen" as CFString,
                                    nil,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.deliverImmediately)
...
private let hasBlankedScreen: CFNotificationCallback = { _, observer, cfName, _, _ in
    let catcher = Unmanaged<AppDelegate>.fromOpaque(observer!).takeUnretainedValue()
    let controller : FlutterViewController = catcher.window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let detectDeviceAwakeiningChanel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "tidy/detectDeviceAwakeining", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    print("Device screen state changed Swift")
    detectDeviceAwakeiningChanel.invokeMethod("deviceScreenStateChanged", arguments: nil)
}
```

All this works perfectly fine until phone sleeps for more than 5 or 7 sec so my question is, how can I listen for screen wake-up in background?